# Drupal OG: invite users by emailing them and allowing them to reject invitation

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, organic-groups

I need to implement the following scenario: when creating an organic group, the OG manager selects a few registered users and invites them to join the group. The invitations are sent as emails (or as Drupal messages in the user's Drupal "inbox") and contain a link for accepting the invitation; if the receiving user clicks on this link, they will join the OG, but if they don't, they will not be made members of the OG.

(At the moment, using the "Manage members" function of the OG, the creator can add members to the team, but the added members have no option of rejecting this)

Can this be achieved with the OG module or some other module (which?) is needed? This functionality is so common that somehow I find it hard to believe there is no module that does this out of the box. 
I could not find much on this topic, though, so I'd be happy for any suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meantime, the [OG Invite Link](http://drupal.org/project/og_invite_link) module has been created and is being continuously updated as a response to the "invite users" discussions in the OG Issues. This is exactly what I needed; posting it here in the hope that it will help others as well.